# Trying to find the median for only even numbers

Tags: java, arrays, median

Hello my code is using arrays. The user  creates an array of intergers .  then I put the numbers the user created into a  for loop. Inside the for loop it will ask the user "please enter a number" the amount of times the user wanted. That part is done my problem is finding the median of the numbers. The problem if the user creates an array of ten or any even number I have to make an if statement that is divisible by 2. What I wrote was

```
 if (numbers % 2.0==0.0){
            ///Don't mind this 
            median=numbers.length/2.0;
            median=median-.5;
            ///
    }
```

When ever I write that code I get an error message that says `The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) Double[], double

Comment: Check data type of your variable "numbers"

Comment: You are trying to apply a `Double` with the module (%) operators. Module operator `%` only works with integers. You have to write `if (numbers % 2==0)` instead.